# Include local assets in dist folder using webpack

Tags: build, webpack, assets

I'm fairly new to webpack and I'm trying to understand what's the proper way to include my assets folder into the `dist` folder using webpack (or one of its plugins).

This is the structure of my project:

```
├── package.json
├── webpack.config.js
├── src
│   ├── index.html
│   ├── app.js
│   ├── components
│   │   ├── ...
│   ├── assets
│   │   ├── factory.png
│   │   ├── factory_white.png
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve my own issue by reading around about [copy-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/kevlened/copy-webpack-plugin)